# NodeJS cors don't filter anything

Tags: node.js, cors

I tried to follow the tutorials I found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and [here](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/). But it appears the routes are accepted no matter what:

```
const config = require('config')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.get('host')+' - '+req.get('origin'))
  res.send('OK')
})

app.get('/test2', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.get('host')+' - '+req.get('origin'))
  res.send('OK2')
})

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(config.get('app.port'))
```

When I enter the URLs in the browser or when I fetch it in the console, I have the same line in the console: `myAPIwebsite.com - undefined` (myAPIwebsite.com is where the node API is accessible).

What I would like is that the `/test` works from anywhere but `/test2` only for requests coming from example.com.

Could anybody give me a hand? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default many/mosts requests that originate from one domain, but go to another domain are blocked. CORS headers allow you to selectively lift those restrictions.

Directly opening a url in your browser addressbar was never blocked, so CORS can't help you 'unblock' what was not blocked in the first place.

The S in CORS stands for sharing. The headers are only for loosening restrictions.

Comment: OK so the tutorials are really misleading, I had the impression you could block requests coming from URLs you didn't allow... Isn't that what the cors packages proposes to do?

Comment: No, again, CORS is for _reducing_ security, not increasing it.

Comment: I wrote something about it here: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think every "CORS" article could give a beginning of explanation on how it's possible to ADD security (i.e. restricting access). In my example, I think I have to check the origin and send a code 500.

Comment: There's so many articles about this, and most of them are bad. Best is to just go to reputable sources like MDN and learn what these things actually do vs. reading more blogspam =)

Comment: Well, I think my digging has just begun then. Thanks a lot for your time and happy new year :)