# CORS configuration OK on the server but client thinks it's not

Tags: nginx, axios, cors

I've a client on a server (https://example.com) and an API on another server (https://api.myapis.com/thisapi)

When my client calls the API server I have this in my NGINX log:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [03/Jan/2021:19:07:03 +0100] "OPTIONS /thisapi/particular/route/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "https://example.com/app/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
```

So I suppose it's OK for the NGINX server, which has this conf:

```
location /thisapi/ {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For$remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
}
```

Here is how I make the API call with axios:

```
  axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/particular/route/`, {
    text: text.value,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      link.value = `${process.env.VUE_APP_URL}${process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLICPATH}${response.data}`;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      loading.value = false;
    });
  return true;
}
```

And I have this in my Firefox console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.myapis.com/thisapi/particular/route/. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed).
```

I really don't see where I messed up... If anybody could give me a hand, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I understood what went wrong, I was mistaken by another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532334/1098303

This experimented user told CORS was to lift restrictions, so that's what I did in my nodeJS app. I added another "Origin", like this:

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'myothersource');
```

That is what made the error.
Now that I removed the header addition in my NodeJS app, everything is find, but I still wonder how you can "lift restrictions" in a NodeJS app compared to what is set on the nginx server, it seems impossible and you might have to choose between an nginx conf or a NodeJS one.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't handle this in Nginx, but rather in the backend itself.

Try:

> add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;

If it now works like you expect it, that means 'https://example.com' is not correct.
(Btw you shouldn't use * in your code, it's just for demonstration purpose.)
Origin is consisted of 3 parts:

- Protocol

  - https
  - http
- Domain Name 
  (like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
- Port
  Usually this is either 80 or 443

Make sure that the origin you are adding to the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ list, is exactly what it should be.

Check whether it is https or http.

## EDITED:

Check the request and response headers.

The bluish parts should be the same.

[image]

If they are not the same for you, that means whatever you are doing, isn't working like it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the precision. Actually the problem was in another place, I put another answer. Thanks for the time you spent helping me and happy new year :)